# Insert space in Pandas Data Frame Column String for each character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame look like below I need to give space between each letter of word in same column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence': ['ABCAD', 'DBAACR']})
df
```

Expected Output

```
sequence
A b C A D
D B A A C R
```

Comment: ``df['sequence'] = df['sequence'].str.join(" ")`` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':['ABCAD','DBAACR']})

A = []
for i in df['sequence']:
  a = (" ".join(i))
  A.append(a)

df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':A})
df
```

If you execute above cell which will return the pandas DataFrame as below.

```
  sequence
0   A B C A D
1   D B A A C R
```

Thanks and don't forget to upvote :D

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame({'sequence':[' '.join('ABCAD'),' '.join('DBAACR')]})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply with lambda function to process columns in pandas data frame

```
df.sequence.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)))
```

Output:

```
0      A B C A D
1    D B A A C R
```